# NoSuchMethodError Java

Tags: java, nosuchmethoderror

I get this runtime error and don't know how to fix:

```
java.lang.NoSucheMethodError: java.io.FileInputStream.transferTo(Ljava/io/OutputStream;)J
```

This happens while using the transferTo method from a FileInputStream to a ZipOutputStream

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName);

    zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

    try {
        fis.transferTo(zos);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Simple: you **compiled** your code against Java 9 (as that method was added with java 9, which you can see in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo-java.io.OutputStream-)), but it seems you are running it against an older java runtime.

That exception **always** tells you that the dependencies you used at compile do not match your run time setup. That is all there is to this.

Comment: Now I'm on java 8 but from the control panel java doesn't find other versions. How can I switch to java 9?

Comment: The point is: where do your compiled java classes from?! Again: the compiled stuff expects a method that was added with java 9. You run that on java 8. I have no idea how you pulled together your classes, and how your setup looks like. I can only tell you what is causing your problem. How you solve your setup, that is your problem. Because you are the master of your setup.

Comment: it is my own program, if I run it on eclipse it doesn't give any problems

Comment: I tried on MacOs, Debian and Windows and the problem only occurred with the latter

Comment: @antonio99 Not sure what else you are looking for. I explained to you the root cause of your problem. You should do some more research to A) understand what java version your eclipse is using (for compiling and running, two different aspects) and B) how your RUNTIME environment is configured. As said: the problem is that you are RUNNING code that uses a java 9 library with a java 8 JRE. You need to look into your setup, and **understand** what I am telling you. But I cant do that for you. It is up to you know to research these topics, and maybe accept some answer at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple reasons for occuring NoSuchMethodError

1) **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError** is being thrown when program tries to call a class method that doesn’t exist. The method can be static or it can be an instance method too.

2) Conflict because of same class name. For example, your application is using some third party jar which has same fully qualified class name as yours. So if classloader loads the class from other jar, you will get **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError** at runtime.

3) Jar version used at the compile time is different from the runtime. For example, you might have MySQL jar in your application having different version from what is present in Tomcat lib folder. Since tomcat lib folder jars are looked first by Java Classloader, there is a chance of **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError** if any method is not found in the class loaded.

Comment: Expect that we are talking about a java.io base package. That should really not come out of any application JAR.